# How to remove underlined in vuetify v-select

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component for `v-select`, for example like this

```
<v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-select
          class="no-border"
          variant="underlined"
          label="Select"
          :items="['California', 'Colorado', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Texas', 'Wyoming']"
        ></v-select>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

And i try to remove using css like this

```css
.v-input--underlined .v-input__control {
  border: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the thin black border on the bottom of the select.

In Vuetify 2, you have to override `.v-input__slot::before`:

```css
.theme--light.v-text-field.no-border > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot::before{
  border-width: 0;
}
```

In Vuetify 3, you have to override `.v-field__outline::before`:

```css
.no-border .v-field--variant-underlined .v-field__outline::before{
  border-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add a custom class to your v-select component

```
<v-select
  class="no-border no-underline"
  variant="underlined"
  label="Select"
  :items="['California', 'Colorado', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Texas', 'Wyoming']"
></v-select>


    .no-underline .v-select__selections {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the .v-field__outline class and use the display none property ,it will remove the border bottom of the select